# merge multiple lines of data having one common field

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl, csv-simple

I have a large file with 9+ rows of data seperates with semi-colon(;) and I want to merge data in column 3 (seperating with ,) the lines where data in column 5 matches. The data is held on a Linux machine and have the usual awk/perl tools but not sure how to use them

**File:**

```
Domain Name;ID;Machine;Environment;ENV URL;Start Date;End Date;Disk Size;Used
orion.uk.localhost.com;XY01123;Machine-apache-ua01;uat;uat.orion.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
orion.uk.localhost.com;XY01123;Machine-apache-ua02;uat;uat.orion.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-dev1;dev;dev.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 06:32:28 GMT+01:00;16 April 2018 07:02:28 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-bcp1;test;test.matrix.localhost.com;2 April 2013 08:12:10 GMT+01:00;2 April 2018 08:42:10 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-dev2;dev;dev.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 06:32:28 GMT+01:00;16 April 2018 07:02:28 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-prd1;test;test.matrix.localhost.com;2 April 2013 08:12:10 GMT+01:00;2 April 2018 08:42:10 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-uat1;uat;uat.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 07:06:33 GMT+01:00;16 April 2018 07:36:33 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-uat2;uat;uat.matrix.localhost.com;22 March 2013 06:16:10 GMT;22 March 2018 06:46:10 GMT;1024;External
Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;IN022345;Machine-apache-pf01;per;per.Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;IN022345;Machine-apache-pf02;per;per.Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Domain Name;ID;Machine;Environment;ENV URL;Start Date;End Date;Disk Size;Used
orion.uk.localhost.com;XY01123;Machine-apache-ua01,Machine-apache-ua02;uat;uat.orion.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-dev1,Machine-apache-dev2;dev;dev.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 06:32:28 GMT+01:00;16 April 2018 07:02:28 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-bcp1;test;test.matrix.localhost.com;2 April 2013 08:12:10 GMT+01:00;2 April 2018 08:42:10 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-prd1;test;test.matrix.localhost.com;2 April 2013 08:12:10 GMT+01:00;2 April 2018 08:42:10 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-uat1,Machine-apache-uat2;uat;uat.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 07:06:33 GMT+01:00;16 April 2018 07:36:33 GMT+01:00;1024;External
Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;IN022345;Machine-apache-pf01,Machine-apache-pf02;per;per.Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
```

Any thoughts on how to merge will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a hash-of-arrays in perl (with splices to remove and re-insert the aggregate field after each merge):

```
$ perl -F\; -alne '

  if($.==1) {
    print;
    next;
  }

  if(!exists $HoA{$F[4]}) {
    $HoA{$F[4]} = [ @F ];
  }
  else {
    splice @{ $HoA{$F[4]} }, 2, 0, join ",", (splice @{ $HoA{$F[4]} }, 2, 1), $F[2];
  }

  END {
    for $k (keys %HoA) {
      print join ";", @{ $HoA{$k} };
    }
  }
  ' data
Domain Name;ID;Machine;Environment;ENV URL;Start Date;End Date;Disk Size;Used
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-bcp1,Machine-apache-prd1;test;test.matrix.localhost.com;2 April 2013 08:12:10 GMT+01:00;2 April 2018 08:42:10 GMT+01:00;1024;External
orion.uk.localhost.com;XY01123;Machine-apache-ua01,Machine-apache-ua02;uat;uat.orion.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-dev1,Machine-apache-dev2;dev;dev.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 06:32:28 GMT+01:00;16 April 2018 07:02:28 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-uat1,Machine-apache-uat2;uat;uat.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 07:06:33 GMT+01:00;16 April 2018 07:36:33 GMT+01:00;1024;External
Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;IN022345;Machine-apache-pf01,Machine-apache-pf02;per;per.Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
```

---

Alternatively, using GNU `datamash` (with a `cut` to remove the superfluous `groupby` field):

```
$ datamash -Hst\; groupby 5 unique 1-2 collapse 3 unique 4-9 < data | cut -d\; -f2-
unique(Domain Name);unique(ID);collapse(Machine);unique(Environment);unique(ENV URL);unique(Start Date);unique(End Date);unique(Disk Size);unique(Used)
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-dev1,Machine-apache-dev2;dev;dev.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 06:32:28 GMT+01:00;16 April 2018 07:02:28 GMT+01:00;1024;External
Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;IN022345;Machine-apache-pf01,Machine-apache-pf02;per;per.Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-bcp1,Machine-apache-prd1;test;test.matrix.localhost.com;2 April 2013 08:12:10 GMT+01:00;2 April 2018 08:42:10 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-uat1,Machine-apache-uat2;uat;uat.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 07:06:33 GMT+01:00,22 March 2013 06:16:10 GMT;16 April 2018 07:36:33 GMT+01:00,22 March 2018 06:46:10 GMT;1024;External
orion.uk.localhost.com;XY01123;Machine-apache-ua01,Machine-apache-ua02;uat;uat.orion.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `sqlite` there? Do I get you right about how to join lines?

```
sqlite> .separator ;
sqlite> .import file.txt alldata
sqlite> select "ENV URL", group_concat("Machine") from alldata group by "ENV URL";
dev.matrix.localhost.com;Machine-apache-dev1,Machine-apache-dev2
per.Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;Machine-apache-pf01,Machine-apache-pf02
test.matrix.localhost.com;Machine-apache-bcp1,Machine-apache-prd1
uat.matrix.localhost.com;Machine-apache-uat1,Machine-apache-uat2
uat.orion.uk.localhost.com;Machine-apache-ua01,Machine-apache-ua02
```

Or non-interactive:

```
echo 'select "ENV URL", group_concat("Machine") from alldata group by "ENV URL";' \
  | sqlite3 -separator ";" -cmd ".import file.txt alldata" -batch
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are much more elegant ways with `awk`, but here is a possible script.

```
BEGIN { FS=";" ; OFS=";" }
NR==1 { print $0 }
NR>1 {
    if ( b[$5]=="" ) {
        a[$5]=$0
        b[$5]=$3
    }
    else {
        b[$5]=b[$5]","$3
        $3=b[$5]
        a[$5]=$0
    }
}
END {
    for (c in a) {
        print a[c]
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- `BEGIN` set semicolon as input and output field separators
- `NR==1` just print the first (header) line, no action needed
- `NR>1` for the other lines:

  - `b[$5]` is an array indexed by field 5 values, containing the (growing) comma-separated list of field 3 entries
  - `a[$5]` is an array indexed by field 5 values, containing the modified lines (i.e. with the comma-separated field 3 valued included)
  - if `b[$5]` is unset (first occurrence of this value), set `a[$5]` as the line and `b[$5]` as field 3
  - otherwise (`b[$5]` is set), add field 3 with a comma delimiter to `b[$5]`, replace field 3 in this line with this and then replace `a[$5]` with this altered line
  - `END` for all index values `c` of array `a` print the array element (i.e. the desired line)

I don't really know how `awk` is sorting the output, but this is my result:

```
Domain Name;ID;Machine;Environment;ENV URL;Start Date;End Date;Disk Size;Used
Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;IN022345;Machine-apache-pf01,Machine-apache-pf02;per;per.Upgrade.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-dev1,Machine-apache-dev2;dev;dev.matrix.localhost.com;16 April 2013 06:32:28 GMT+01:00;16 April 2018 07:02:28 GMT+01:00;1024;External
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-uat1,Machine-apache-uat2;uat;uat.matrix.localhost.com;22 March 2013 06:16:10 GMT;22 March 2018 06:46:10 GMT;1024;External
orion.uk.localhost.com;XY01123;Machine-apache-ua01,Machine-apache-ua02;uat;uat.orion.uk.localhost.com;5 August 2015 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2 August 2025 16:54:08 GMT+01:00;2048;Internal
matrix.localhost.com;XY6124;Machine-apache-bcp1,Machine-apache-prd1;test;test.matrix.localhost.com;2 April 2013 08:12:10 GMT+01:00;2 April 2018 08:42:10 GMT+01:00;1024;External
```